# Passing MsBuild Command Line Arguments with BuildEngine

Tags: c#, msbuild, msbuild-buildengine

I have the following code to build a project from another C# app:

```
var buildEngine = new Engine();

buildEngine.RegisterLogger(new ConsoleLogger());

var success = buildEngine.BuildProjectFile(pathToCsProjFile);
if(!success)
{
    Log.LogIt("On Noes! We Broke!");
}
else
{
    Log.LogIt("It Worked!!!!!!");
}
```

Currently it builds the default configuration (Debug) but I want it to build the release version. If I were invoking MsBuild from the command line I would do something like:

```
C:\Windows\WinFX\v3.5>msbuild.exe *.proj /ToolsVersion:3.5 /p:Configuration=Release
```

How do I pass that configuration switch to the build engine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to set the property, something like this should do the trick:

```
var pathToCsProjFile = "";
var buildEngine = new Engine();
var project = new Project(buildEngine);
project.Load(pathToCsProjFile);
project.SetProperty("Configuration", "Release");

var success = project.Build();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use one of the other overloaded implementations of `BuildProjectFile`.  I believe this [one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221775.aspx).  Create a `BuildPropertyGroup` and add the properties you want.  In this case 'Configuration' = 'Release'